# Progress list-view item background color depends on music player progress

Tags: android

I have a list of songs and want to progress background color that song which is currently playing  as like as seek bar or progress bar.It should be able to progress background color when my song finishes and goes to next one. Please give any idea or source code how implement this feature. Advance thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to take song length in milliseconds and use it as 100% of progress bar.

`MediaPlayer` allows you to do that:

```
public long getSoundDuration(Context context, String file){

    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = context.getAssets().openFd(file);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());

        player.prepare();

        int duration = player.getDuration();
        player.release();
        return duration;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

So now when you have duration, its easy to convert to progress bar value.

Hope it will help you